glassfish server 4.0 could not start with jdk 21
It gives dialogbox: Glassfish server could not be started with jdk21, please select another java SE platform.
manage platforms
cancel
after click on cancel it gives information: could not find java SE development kit to start Glassfish server.
Starting GlassFish Server
Could not find Java SE Development Kit to start GlassFish Server
C:\Users\admin\Documents\NetBeansProjects\WebApplication1\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1030: Deployment error: Could not find Java SE Development Kit to start GlassFish Server
See the server log for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 17 minutes 47 seconds)
how to manage plateform or which are the suitable versions of servlet for netbeans 21 , jdk 21?

Just research what the currently available GlassFish version is.

Glassfish 4.0 is ancient (11 years old), current version is 7.0.16 (https://glassfish.org/download.html) which is also compatible with JDK 21. How to change JDK in NetBeans: https://netbeans.apache.org/tutorial/main/kb/docs/java/javase-jdk8/

To run GlassFish 4, you need Java 8 or older. You need to download and install Java 8 into Netbeans and then select it to run GlssFish.
I would highly recommend upgrading to GlassFish 7, which runs on Java 21 and is fully supported on a recent version of Netbeans.
For a list of currently supported releases of GlassFish, see this page and the GitHub page.



GlassFish
Jakarta EE
Java




8.x
11
17+


7.x
10
11+


6.x
9.1
8+


5.x
8
8




after adding glassfish 7.0.11 it gives error :Could not start GlassFish Server: HTTP or HTTPS listener port is occupied while server is not running
C:\Users\admin\Documents\NetBeansProjects\servlet_glassfish\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1055: Deployment error: Could not start GlassFish Server: HTTP or HTTPS listener port is occupied while server is not running
See the server log for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

Maybe you have some other GlassFish running? Or some other process running on port 8080 or 8181? Try restarting Windows.

If you need more help with GlassFish, feel free to contact me at https://omnifish.ee/contact-us/. At OmniFish, we also help with upgrading to GlassFish 7, if you need to upgrade older apps from GlassFish 4.
